# NativeScript FontAwesome 5 free version overwrites regular font by solid font in iOS

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular, font-awesome-5

Trying to use the below font to show user icon using FontAwesome 5 in Nativescript, the user icon with regular view is loading correctly in Android.

But in iOS version the icon is overwritten with Solid font.

```
<Label class="page-icon far" text="&#xf007;"></Label>
```

when I try to remove the solid font from Fonts folder, it is working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is Font Awesome uses the SAME `Family` name for the Solid and Regular collections.  The `.ttf` files differentiate collections based on `Style`, which is not supported in CSS.

The solution is to rename the `Family` of one of the collections - I choose solid.

I wrote an in depth [blog post](https://rynop.com/2018/12/27/get-font-awesome-5-working-with-nativescript-angular-mobile-app/), but the gist is:

1. Copy .ttf files into your `fonts` dir
2. Use [fontname.py](https://github.com/chrissimpkins/fontname.py) (or similar tool) to rename the `Family` attribute:

`python fontname.py "Font Awesome 5 Free Solid" fa-solid-900.ttf`

You can then specify the following in your css:

```
.far {
    font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free', fa-regular-400;
}

.fab {
    font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Brands', fa-brands-400;
}

.fas {
    font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free Solid', fa-solid-900;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps?

https://medium.com/@fransyozef/how-i-got-fontawesome-5-working-with-my-angular-nativescript-mobile-app-d7605930d7c9

I had also a lot of problems with FontAwesome 5, fixed it so decided to make a blog post out of it :)

Comment: Your `far` does not work on iOS.  A good test is `f2bb` there is a solid and regular variant.  I can't get any of the `Regular` icons to work.

Answer (score 0):

Font Awesome 5 add in nativescript Angular in Android and ios
use

```
.fa {
    font-family: "FontAwesome";
}
```

app.android.css
[image]
app.ios.css
[image]
app/fonts
[download](https://fontawesome.com/download)
[image]